# How to obtain data from a marker in VSA software that is running on a computer?

Tags: python, automated-tests

I am using Keysight Command Expert to help me to develop automated testing. I set a marker to try to obtain the result from OBW and ACP measurement. However, I didn't find appropriate SCPI commands for 89600VSA software that is running on the computer that will allow me to read data from the marker or allow me to create a new trace that can be set to display the data of either measurement. Please help.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the end, the code I used for creating an OBW or ACP window is

```
:TRACe3:DATA:NAME "Obw Summary TrcA"
:TRACe3:DATA:NAME "Acp Summary TrcA"
```

This creates an Obw or Acp data summary of trace 1 in the third window. Normally, you will create an empty trace beforehand simply by using

```
:TRACe1:ADD
```

This [webpage](https://rfmw.em.keysight.com/wireless/helpfiles/89600b/WebHelp-scpi/scpiref.htm) tells me how to formulate an SCPI command that is equivalent to an instruction set by using GUI. In short, go to **Window > Output** and click **Show Code** checkbox to enable. This shows the .NET API command that is sent to the instrument when you perform an operation. Then, take the last bit of the .NET API command which is after '.' to find an equivalent SCPI command.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/32250713)

Comment: I include the codes that I used for solving the problem so I undelete the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the helpfile for `marker`, the 100th entry is Examples and in there you'll find a lot of SCPI code including:

```
Working with Markers
    :INIT:IMM;*OPC?
    TRACe1:MARKer1:MAX
    TRACe1:MARKer1:Y?
    TRACe1:MARKer1:X?
    TRACe1:MARKer2:MAX
    TRACe1:MARKer2:DOWN
    TRAC:MARK2:TYPE DELTA
```

This gives you an idea of some of the different commands available.